# Post data to A URL by C#

Tags: json, wcf, post, request, get

How can I Post for example this information of below to this website "http://restapi.adequateshop.com/api/Tourist"
by C# code?

tourist_name:   "dummy"
tourist_email:  "test123@test.com"
tourist_location:   "Paris"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create the constructor with post type and few data
            string data = "tourist_name=Mike&tourist_email=miked123@gmail.com&tourist_location=Paris";
            MyWebRequest myRequest = new MyWebRequest("http://restapi.adequateshop.com/api/Tourist", "POST", data);
            //show the response string on the console screen.
            string Response = myRequest.GetResponse();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your data in a new class :

```
class RequestData
{
  string tourist_name { get; set; }
  string tourist_email { get; set; }
  string tourist_location { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can serialize your object to JSON:

```
RequestData requestData = new RequestData();
requestData.tourist_name ="Mike";
requestData.tourist_email ="miked123@gmail.com";
requestData.tourist_location ="Paris";

string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData);
```

Then send your JSON to API

```
string URL="http://restapi.adequateshop.com/api/Tourist";
var jsonContent = new StringContent(jsonData,Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
var result = client.PostAsync(URL,jsonContent).Result;
```

I hope this answers your question.